# Прибавление к значению ползунка

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт ползунка, выводит два одинаковых значения, нужно ко второму выводу прибавить его же воловину. Например ползунок остановлен на 1000, нужно вывести 1500, остановлен на 50, нужно вывести 75.

html:

```
    <div id="slider-result">50</div>
    <center>
    <input id="text" type="text" />
    </center>
```

скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
             $( ".slider" ).slider({
            animate: true,
            range: "min",
            value: 50,
            min: 50,
            max: 15000,
            step: 50,

            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider-result" ).html(ui.value);
            },

            change: function(event, ui) {
            $('#text').attr('value', ui.value);
            }

            });
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено.

```
change: function(event, ui) {
$('#text').attr('value', ui.value*1.5);
}
});
```